# Can Microsoft Edge be added to Photoshop Save for Web Preview?

Tags: windows, windows-10, adobe-photoshop, microsoft-edge

The Save for Web dialogue in Adobe Photoshop allows for previewing an image in a browser...

[image: Photoshop Save for Web screen snip]

I have tried adding Edge to the list of browsers by adding it from the following location:

`C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe`

However when I click preview Edge does not open.

Can Microsoft Edge be added to Photoshop Save for Web Preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Edge is not a "normal" Windows application, so it isn't invoked via an EXE file like you've become accustomed to.

So, you just need a small utility that creates an EXE file that will launch Edge.  The coding is quite simple... just a few lines of code.  I wrote one:

http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeLaunch.html

After installing this tiny utility, you can then point Photoshop to EdgeLaunch instead.